# If $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} :(f\circ g)(x)=(g\circ f)(x)=x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R} :(f\circ g)(x)=(g\circ f)(x)=x$$
the **only result** can be $f^{-1}=g$?
or, there is **other possible result** ?

Can we prove the first claim (as only possibilities )?

I was thinking about it a week,but I get stuck on this .

Thanks for any idea in advance .

Comment: How do you **define** $f^{-1}$?

Comment: $f \circ g(x) = x$ for all $x$, means that $g$ is a right inverse of $f$, and $f$ is a left inverse of $g$. And $g \circ f(x) = x$ for all $x$, means that $f$ is a right inverse of $f$, and $g$ is a left inverse of $f$. Combining these two statements, $g$ is a left and right inverse of $f$, therefore it is an inverse of $f$. Since inverses are unique, $g$ is **the** inverse of $f$, namely $f^{-1}$. Likewise, $f = g^{-1}$.

Comment: Btw, you can make text bold using `**text_here**`

Comment: Essentially, this is a question about uniqueness of inverse. It works in any category. It would be more transparent if $f^{-1}$ notation wasn't used.

Answer (score 5):

Yes ! Let define $f^{-1}$ as the inverse of $f$.

$$f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}\circ (f\circ g)(x)=(f^{-1}\circ f)\circ g(x)=g(x).$$

Comment: Yes ?! it means that the only inverse function property ?

Comment: @Khosrotash functional inverses are unique, just like how additive and multiplicative inverses are unique.  The proof for each of which follows closely to the above.

Comment: It's worth noting that we first deduce the existence of $f^{-1}$ by the given facts that $f$ has a left inverse (so $f$ is injective) and a right inverse (so $f$ is surjective).

Comment: And the same line as in the answer proves that if $f$ has both left and right inverse, they must be equal.